# Android: Can not send http post

Tags: java, android, http-post

I've been banging my head trying to figure out how to send a post method in Android. This is how my code look like:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {    
        HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/");
        httpMethod.addHeader("Accept", "text/html");
        httpMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");


        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpMethod);
            textView.setText(response.toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            Log.i(HomeActivity.class.toString(), result);
            textView.setText("Invoked webservice");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(HomeActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            textView.setText("Something wrong:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception that I get:

```
I/ARMAssembler(   59): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [
 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x334348:0x334510] in 1430659 ns
W/System.err(  272): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.example.com
W/System.err(  272):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.jav
a:513)
W/System.err(  272):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.jav
a:278)
W/System.err(  272):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:24
2)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOper
ator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(Abst
ractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.o
pen(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.ex
ecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
e(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
e(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err(  272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
e(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHtt
pClient.java:243)
W/System.err(  272):    at com.collaboapp.android.HomeActivity.onClick(HomeActiv
ity.java:152)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(  272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4
627)
W/System.err(  272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(  272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err(  272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCalle
r.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err(  272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.ja
va:626)
W/System.err(  272):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/class android.HomeActivity(  272): www.example.com
D/ThrottleService(   59): finally have imsi - retreiving data
D/ThrottleService(   59): onPollAlarm - roaming =false, read =0, written =0, new
 total =0
D/SntpClient(   59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything that I may need to configure from the Android emulator to get this working?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the error / Exception you see?

Comment: So how do you know then that it doesn't work? can you look at the access logs on the server side and see no entry or have a proxy inbetween that gets no requests?

Comment: @ZeissS. Okay now I found out how to get the log.

Comment: Seems like your android is unable to lookup the DNS Entry `www.example.com`. Does it have a working internet connection?

Comment: Yup. It has internet connection. I can browse the internet using the emulator's browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems that AndroidHttpClient is responsible for that exception. Your example will work

- if use set the 'INTERNET' persmission as suggested
- replace 'AndroidHttpClient' with 'DefaultHttpClient'
- remove the line 'Log.i(HomeActivity.class.toString(), result);' because result is null

It is not clear to me why this class does not work as excpected, maybe somebody could explain. This thread discussed the problem too but there is also no explaination why the code fails: http://groups.google.de/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cc59efb9475ac557/81116369f2c6bd7a?hl=de&lnk=gst&q=This+thread+forbids+HTTP+requests#81116369f2c6bd7a.

Comment: It does this because HTTP requests could hold up the UI thread.  AndroidHttpClient is only supposed to be run on a background thread (e.g. in an AsyncTask).  http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html "AndroidHttpClient does not allow itself to be started from the main thread"

Answer (score 6):

You can't call the web from the UI thread so you don't halt the app's UI, this blog post explains it with an example app using AndroidHttpClient: [Official Android Dev Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).

Here is a quote:

> ...this is such a bad idea that the AndroidHttpClient does not allow itself to be started from the main thread. The above code will display "This thread forbids HTTP requests" error messages instead. Use the DefaultHttpClient instead if you really want to shoot yourself in the foot.

So if you really want to run this on UI thread (bad idea, from personal experience and that blog post) then use DefaultHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have uses-permission in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: W/dalvikvm(  261): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  261): java.lang.RuntimeException: This thread forbids HTTP re
quests

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , I found [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html), I had just enable the StrictMode

```
 public void onCreate() {
 if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
     StrictMode.enableDefaults();
 }
 super.onCreate();
```

}