# Android Honeycomb: NetworkOnMainThreadException even when using AsyncTask and no strict mode?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-strictmode

I run into a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) with my Android 3.0 app.
Searching for a solution I found [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html), but if I understand this correctly, default setting would be that the strict mode is turned off.

Also, all my network access is in an `AsyncTask`, so I don't see the point in this Exception anyway.

So, I'm quite desperate now what I should do to prevent this...

Kind regards,
jellyfish

**Edit:**

[This blog entry](http://rashidnoorani.blogspot.com/2011/04/why-do-you-get-androidosnetworkonmainth.html) says that AsyncTask should be enough, but at least clarifies the StrictMode point.

**Solution:**

I turned off the StrictMode (its probably better to keep some settings but I couldn't be bothered...):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

After that, I did run into a "java.lang.RuntimeException: This thread forbids HTTP requests", but found a solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032042/android-can-not-send-http-post). I'm a bit confused, though, as `AndroidHttpClient` worked fine when I used it in my Android 2.0+ app...

**Solution, part2**

As it turned out, using AsyncTask was a nice idea but pretty useless if [done wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412464/android-honeycomb-fragment-not-able-to-start-asynctask)...
So there was nothing wrong with the strict mode's reaction. Should have listened, er? ;)

Still good to know it's activated on Honeycomb by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StrictMode is turned on by default in Honeycomb.

See say [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html#penaltyDeathOnNetwork()) specifically `penaltyDeathOnNetwork()`. I ran into a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you... this new API is driving me crazy. ^^ I don't get it why an AsyncTask isn't considered to be out of the main thread...

Comment: I agree. What's wrong with Thread.run()? Why do they even need that?

Answer (score 14):

In Android Honeycomb StrictMode is enabled, turn it off adding the code on the onCreate() function...

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);       
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Comment: This code may be the correct way to change the policy, but it's almost always the wrong way to handle `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.  If you check the OP's update, you'll see that they were just improperly using `AsyncTask`.  But, `AsyncTask`, or some other mechanism of getting network traffic off the UI thread, is basically always a better solution than this policy change hack.